# Как получить массив с индексом и значениями в примере?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

Использую sortable 
Вот весь js код

```
        $(function() {
    a = [ ];
    $("#head").disableSelection();
    $('#variants').sortable({connectWith: '.sortContainer'});

    var oldList, newList, item;
    $( ".sortContainer" ).sortable({
          start: function(event, ui) {
            item = ui.item;
            newList = oldList = ui.item.parent().parent();
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {  
            if(ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent().parent();
        },
        connectWith: '#variants,.sortContainer',
        receive: function(event, ui) {

          a.push(ui.item.attr("id"));
          alert(a+newList.attr('id'));
        },
        remove: function(event, ui) {

         a.splice(a.indexOf('bar'), 1);

        alert(a);
        }
    });

    $("#appendb").click(function() {
      random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 90 ) + 10; 
    $('#variants').append("<div id='ans_"+random+"'  class='variantions ui-state-error'>"+$( "#newans" ).val()+"</div>");
  });

  $("#appenq").click(function() {
 random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 90 ) + 10; 
    $('.answers').append('<div class="answer" id="B'+random+'"> <div id="current" class="title">'+$("#newans").val()+'</div>  <div class="sortContainer" id="'+random+'"></div>');
    $( ".sortContainer" ).sortable({
      start: function(event, ui) {
            item = ui.item;
            newList = oldList = ui.item.parent().parent();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {          
            alert("Moved " + item.text() + " from " + oldList.attr('id') + " to " + newList.attr('id'));
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {  
            if(ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent().parent();
        },
        connectWith: '#variants,.sortContainer',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
        },
        remove: function(event, ui) {

           a.splice(a.indexOf('bar'), 1);

        }
    });

  });



});
```

Как мне получить данные в виде id блока (как индекс) в который перемещаем значения (как значения)
Чтобы получить массив типа такого:

```
arr = [{ idблока: 'idзначения' }, { idблока: 'idзначения' }];
```

И чтобы соответственно при добавлении значения в блок в массив добавлялось это значение с ключом (id) блока в который перемещено значение, а при удалении значения из блока - соответственно удалялось.

Рабочий пример здесь:
https://jsfiddle.net/morrowinds/kb18ncgm/29/

Comment: `arr = { idблока: 'idзначения', idблока: 'idзначения' };` это у вас не массив, а объект, чтобы получить массив нужно сделать такую конструкцию: `arr = [{ idблока: 'idзначения' }, { idблока: 'idзначения' }];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление объекта с данными в массив:

```
var a = [];
a.push({parentID: 'id родителя', itemId:  'id элемента' });
```

Удаление объекта из массива:

```
var itemIndex = getValue(a, 'id элемента');
a.splice(itemIndex, 1);

function getValue(array, itemId) {
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i].itemId == itemId) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

[Итоговый пример](https://jsfiddle.net/kb18ncgm/31/), с реализацией этого функционала на примере автора, смотреть за состоянием массива можно в консоле.